# PHP code doesn't create the database

Tags: php, mysql, database

In my web application, it has a self installing functionality so, after it is copied to the server, you just need to run the install.php file which has the following PHP code.

```
define("DB_SERVER","localhost");
define("DB_USER","db_user");
define("DB_PASS","pass");

//create mysql connection
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    die("Connection Error");
}else{
    echo "MySQL Connection Successful!";
}


//create database if not exists
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE equiz";
$mysqlQuery = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

if($mysqlQuery){
    echo "Database Created Successfully";
}else{
    die("Database Not Created!");
}
```

In the localhost, this works perfectly fine. But, when this is moved to the server, it gives me this error

**`Access denied for user 'db_user'@'localhost' to database 'equiz'`**

I had created the user `db_user` in advance along with another database and I'm sure he was granted with all the permissions. ***But I'm not sure if those permissions were for that particular database only.***

Anyway any clue for this error ? I know little bit PHP but very new to real world web servers.

Comment: can't see the db name .

Comment: create an another user and try once, it will hardly take 5 min.

Comment: set full access database Privilege on server

Comment: There is db name. First create the mysql connection and then creates the database in the second query

Comment: @Anant I did create another user there's no option to add privileges unless I add that user to a database. What I need is create the DB by my PHP application. Not manually.

Comment: Anyone who down vote, be an adult to mention why.

Comment: `define("DB_SERVER","localhost");
define("DB_USER","root");
define("DB_PASS","");` try once

Comment: It could be that your hosting provider has a setup with a database already created to which you add tables rather than creating the DB from scratch yourself

Comment: @Anant there's no user called root. So, why using root to connect ?

Comment: Have you used this command?? GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'db_user'@'localhost';

Comment: @TharinduLucky try out running my queries that I have posted below. It should work our for you.

Answer (score 2):

The key here is:

```
Access denied for user 'db_user'@'localhost' to database 'equiz'
```

If it's your localhost, then probably you gotten phpMyAdmin installed. You need to grant access rights to your db_user. How to do this, there's explicit manual:

http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/privileges.html

You also can do it manually, if you don't have phpMyAdmin installed, [reference the official MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html), or [tutorials](https://kyup.com/tutorials/create-new-user-grant-permissions-mysql/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set privilege for that user:

```
GRANT INSERT, SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE ON database.* TO 'db_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Then try running your code.

If the above does not work out try creating the user will all rights:

```
CREATE USER 'user_name'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'user_name'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

**To create using PHP:**

//Creation of user "user_name"

```
$mysqli->("CREATE USER 'user_name'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass_word';");
```

//Creation of database "new_db"

```
$mysqli->("CREATE DATABASE `new_db`;");
```

//Adding all privileges on our newly created database

```
$mysqli->("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on `new_db`.* TO 'user_name'@'%';");
```

**Update:**

Connect to database

```
// localhost <==> user_name <==> password <==> database
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user_id", "passwlrd", "db_name");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) 
{
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: I think you need also to add CREATE privilege, as he tries to create the DB from PHP. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala Thanks, your code make sense, but let me clear this out, before your first query `create user` runs, `mysqli_connection` needs to be initialized. Right ? So, how to initialize mysqli connection before creating a user ? `mysqli_connect()` function needs a user.

Comment: @TharinduLucky u must be having a user with admin rights. Use those credentials there.

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala, Well, that makes sense, but, how to know whether I have a user with admin rights ?  or If not how to create him ?

Comment: @TharinduLucky normally your server login details are same as your database login. Unless some one has changed it. And the server login details by default have all the rights (query) to database.

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala I tried with that credentials too. But, it says that user doens't have create previleges.